# TFS Build controller and extensions

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am setting up a TFS 2012 Build server.  I am using some extensions (NUnit Test Adapter).  Per the instructions, I have added the dlls to a common folder in TFS, and configured the "Version Control Path to Custom Assemblies" on the build controller to reference the correct folder in TFS.

Everything works, BUT:  According to the docs, I can create subfolders under my "Path to custom assemblies" folder, and the controller should pick them up.

That doesn't seem to be working for me.  If I put the NUnit support in the root, it works, in subfolders, it does not.

I would like to use the subfolders feature so that I can keep each set of extensions/custom build targets, etc separate.

Does this just not work, or am I missing something?

**Edit**

As requested, here is a reference to the documentation where I found the information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee330987(v=vs.120).aspx#custom_process

Here's the passage:

*To enable your build processes to leverage these kinds of code, check the binaries in to the folder (or any of its descendant folders) that you specify in the Version control path to custom assemblies box.*

Comment: pleas add a reference to the docs that describe that subfolders are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation is just wrong -- all of the dlls must go into 1 folder.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0059bc66-d3c9-42e6-8d8a-dd22f3416e07/version-control-path-to-custom-assemblies-doesnt-use-subfolders?forum=tfsbuild

I do understand that helps to ensure that you don't get duplicate dependencies with different versions -- makes sense.  It just makes it a little tougher to know what depends upon what if you add a few extensions.  Seems to work fine using a single folder, though.